# Key error in pandas (First time programming)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I am a beginner in programming and I am currently learning KNN models.

I wrote a code but I am getting key error and can't fix it.

I am watching a machine learning tutorial on youtube by "Tech With Tim" and this code is in his 5th video on ["Python Machine Learning Tutorial" series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddqQUz9mZaM&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-mP7qA9cagf68V06sko5otr&index=5).
The data that I used is the "Car Evaluation" dataset from UCI machine learning repository.
I wrote the exact same code but I keep getting the following error.

This is the code I wrote

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model, preprocessing

data = pd.read_csv("car.data")
print(data.head())

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
buying = le.fit_transform(list(data["buying"]))
maint = le.fit_transform(list(data["maint"]))
door = le.fit_transform(list(data["door"]))
persons = le.fit_transform(list(data["persons"]))
lug_boot = le.fit_transform(list(data["lug_boot"]))
safety = le.fit_transform(list(data["safety"]))
cls = le.fit_transform(list(data["cls"]))

predict = "class"

x = list(zip(buying, maint, door, persons, lug_boot, safety))
y = list(cls)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

print(x_train, y_test)
```

and this is the error that I got

```
C:\Users\computer\anaconda3\envs\tensor\pythonw.exe "C:/Users/computer/PycharmProjects/TensorEnv2/test 2.py"
  buying  maint  door  persons  lug_boot  safety    cls
0  vhigh  vhigh     2        2     small     low  unacc
1  vhigh  vhigh     2        2     small     med  unacc
2  vhigh  vhigh     2        2     small    high  unacc
3  vhigh  vhigh     2        2       med     low  unacc
4  vhigh  vhigh     2        2       med     med  unacc

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\computer\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'maint'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/computer/PycharmProjects/TensorEnv2/test 2.py", line 13, in <module>
    maint = le.fit_transform(list(data["maint"]))
  File "C:\Users\computer\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\computer\anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'maint'
```

Comment: weird... I don't see any problem too

Comment: Tech With Tim tutorial on Machine Learning, huh...

Comment: NOICE I actually encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error than you and I solved it putting `buying,maint,door,persons,lug_boot,safety,class` in the file car.data. The error was this `buying ,maint ,door ,persons ,lug_boot ,safety ,class`